# SQL combine multiple records into 1 line by date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to find the time-elapsed between consecutive (according to a date field) records in a log table...

For example,

[image]

These are log records for processes that I have running every day. I want to make a report with various fields like Start and End Date, minutes elapsed, etc, but to simplify the "core" of my problem I think I need to figure out how to get these start-and-end records (marked by the comment field) into a single line which would represent 1 run of the process run. I've tried pivot table, but I couldn't get that to work since I couldn't use "Order by date" with the Pivot, which I think is what I would need in order for the "Max" aggregate to be useful. I've tried grouping...I almost got it to work with a self-join using "Row_Number()" and joining Row_Number() to RowNumber+1 (since each start time is off by 1 row compared to the last start..)

but then I found a few records where that wasn't the case.  I imagine this basic task has been done many times but I haven't found my solution yet.

How can I simply take each process run (defined by the "start" and presumably the nearest "end" date) and combine them into one line so I can do further aggregates?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, do you always know that the values are interleaved?

Comment: I can't tag my database as it's not public. But, I would think that the start and end follow the pattern shown (start, then end) but I would think my solution by joining on RowNumber() and RowNumber()+1 would have worked.  But I saw some rare occurences where the start dates were consecutive (no end date inbetween)...I suppose if there are errors in my processes then the end dates wouldn't always get logged...?

Comment: Your database is private? You mean you run a completely custom DBMS? That's unusual. Most people use something like SQL Server, mySQL, Oracle, one of those. That's what Gordon meant by "tag your database". You don't need to reveal irrelevant specifics about all your tables and data, but you do need to tell us which product you use. The syntax and functions available for an answer can vary between different vendors.

Comment: Ohh, ok.  It's SQL (T-SQL). Let me figure out how to tag SQL. Sorry I thought I did that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "next" record is always the ending record, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(log_date) over (order by log_date) as end_log_date
      from t
     ) t
where comment = 'Start tf_crediting : FULL';
```

If you want the next end date, then a cumulative conditional minimum does what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when comment = 'end Crediting' then log_date end) over (order by log_date desc) as end_log_date
      from t
     ) t
where comment = 'Start tf_crediting : FULL';
```

Comment: This appears to do the job, thank you! ...I have to study this syntax a little more with "Over." I've only used it with RowNumber() and partition but I don't know if I really understood the use of "over" itself.  This may help me with other problems too :)